# Database error from mongoengine max_distance query

Tags: python, django, pymongo, mongoengine

Hi i have a problem with queries data using mongoengine. I try to do this same like in documentation but i have a problem.

I create two models

```
class Alarm(mongoengine.Document):
    added = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    title = mongoengine.StringField()
    tracks = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Track))

    meta = {
        'indexes': [[("tracks.location", "2dsphere")]]
    }

class Track(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    created_on = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    location = mongoengine.PointField()
```

from django shell i add one row :

```
db.alarm.insert({"title": "Warszawa", "tracks": [{"location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [21.01666, 52.233333]}}]})
```

I connect to mongodb and from shell i try to find my new location using $near:

```
>db.alarm.find({'tracks.location': {$near: {$geometry: {"type": "Point", coordinates: [18.068611, 59.329444]}, $maxDistance: 810997}}})
>


> db.alarm.find({'tracks.location': {$near: {$geometry: {"type": "Point", coordinates: [18.068611, 59.329444]}, $maxDistance: 810998}}})
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("53ef89626dda06655a57a342"), "title" : "Warszawa",
"tracks" : [ { "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [
21.01666, 52.233333 ] } } ] }
```

Returned result is that what i expected. First query return none second find my location.

But i cannot receive this same result using mongoengine

```
Alarm.objects(tracks__location__near = {"coordinates":[ 21.01666, 52.233333 ] , "type": "Point"}, tracks__location__max_distance=810998)
```

i get:

```
<repr(<mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet at 0x7ff3a50e8a10>) failed: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 810998>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a hint, but:

`$near` operator in MongoDB has two subclauses: `$geometry` and `$maxDistance` (that's how you call it in the Mongo shell). But it looks like your custom object tries to instantiate `$near` clause with only `$geometry` as parameter.

So it's not `tracks__location__max_distance`, but rather something like `tracks__location__near__max_distance` (i.e. max_distance should be inside `$near` clause).

Comment: $maxDistance must be in $geometry clause not in $near. This problem with i get means that $maxDistance is in $near clause. In mongo shell: `> db.alarm.find({'tracks.location': {$near: {$geometry: {"type": "Point", coordinates: [18.068611, 59.329444]}}, $maxDistance: 810999}})
error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 810999.0",
 "code" : 17287
}`

Comment: @gameboy's comment was the cure for my query. $maxDistance must be in the $geometry clause not in the $near clause.